Problem in comments
I have used the package algorithmic, to describe an algorithm, but when I want to add a comment besides the If condition, the compilator outputs an error
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{etoolbox} 


    \begin{document}
    \begin{algorithm}[ht]
        \caption{ algorithm}
        \label{alg7}
        \renewcommand{\algorithmicrequire}{\textbf{Input:}}
        \renewcommand{\algorithmicensure}{\textbf{Output:}}
        \begin{algorithmic}[1]
            \REQUIRE A Set
            \ENSURE A Set
            \STATE Compute  X
            \STATE $k=2$
            \STATE Compute FG
            \WHILE{$k\leq 1+n$}
            \FOR{$j=k$ down to $1$}
            \STATE Set c  \hfill // (\textbf{\textit{Condition1}})
            \ENDFOR
            \IF {$A>B$ } \hfill // (\textbf{\textit{Condition2}})
            \STATE $k=k+1$ 
            \ELSE
            \STATE $v_{k-1}=x$ 
            \STATE $k=1$
            \ENDIF
            \ENDWHILE
    
        \end{algorithmic}
    \end{algorithm}
    \end{document}

I want ot add Condition 2 like Condition 1, so how to solve this problem ?

I believe that you can comment (with \COMMENT) only \STATE lines.

I don't think you can comment on \IF lines, just on \STATE ones.
You may want to switch to algpseudocodex. The package doesn't allow to customize comments so that they're bold italic; changing this is not difficult.
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[
  noEnd=false,
  beginComment=,
  indLines=false,
]{algpseudocodex}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\algpx@commentFormat}[1]{%
  \textbf{(\textit{#1})}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[htp]
\caption{algorithm}
\label{alg7}

\renewcommand{\algorithmicrequire}{\textbf{Input:}}
\renewcommand{\algorithmicensure}{\textbf{Output:}}

\begin{algorithmic}[1]
  \Require A Set
  \Ensure A Set
  \State Compute  X
  \State $k=2$
  \State Compute FG
  \While{$k\leq 1+n$}
    \For{$j=k$ down to $1$}
      \State Set c \Comment{Condition 1}
    \EndFor
    \If {$A>B$} \Comment{Condition 2}
      \State $k=k+1$ 
    \Else
      \State $v_{k-1}=x$ 
      \State $k=1$
    \EndIf
  \EndWhile
\end{algorithmic}

\end{algorithm}

\end{document}


